# Py: List materials with texture used by mesh

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I have a script that list vertices and faces but now I need to get the texture associated with each face, known that only one texture is in each material , only one mesh is in the scene and it is selected . 
I only found the way to list the texture associated using the uv image editor ...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using blender internal, a material can use up to 18 textures to get it's final appearance. An objects face can have one material assigned to it, any and all textures in that material are used by the face.

In object mode you can get the texture used by each face with

```
obj = bpy.context.object
for f in obj.data.polygons:
    for t in obj.material_slots[f.material_index].material.texture_slots:
        if t is not None:
            print("Face %d uses texture %s"%(f.index,t.name))
```

Of course this is using Blender Internal, for cycles you will need to walk through the nodetree to find the nodes your interested in.

Comment: It's almost that. It displays the texture name, I didn't say but I need the texture "filename", I don't find how to get it now...

Comment: I just find that obj.material_slots.material.texture_slots[0].texture.image.name give me the texture name with .00X for dupplicate, I think I can work with it...