# Is it possible to set names of objects based on their texture name?

Tags: uv, unity

I'm trying to import texture wrapped models into Unity 3D.

Unity needs to have the object name the same as the texture name for it to automatically assign the textures.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of python is in order

Comment: Does [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26990/935) provide enough info or do you need more specific help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is for texture name assuming the texture is on the first material :

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

objects = [obj for obj in D.objects if obj.type == 'MESH']

for obj in objects :
   nodes = obj.material_slots[0].material.node_tree.nodes
   tex_node = next((node for node in nodes if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE'), None)
   if tex_node :
       img_name = tex_node.image.name
       img_name = img_name.replace('.jpg','')
       obj.name = img_name.replace('.png','')
```

incase its the material name :

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

objects = [obj for obj in D.objects if obj.type == 'MESH']

for obj in objects :
   obj.name = obj.material_slots[0].material.name
   #obj.material_slots[0].material.name = obj.name   #if it's the other way
```